# Cannot update ticketnumber field on incident

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Does anyone know of any way to update the ‘ticketnumber’ field on an ‘incident’ entity after the incident has already been created?
The field is locked down on the front end and have tried via the API using C# code however this fails to write also?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you need to do, but you can write a pre-operation plugin working on the create message of the incident to override the ticket number that has been assigned set as the default.

We do this to enable custom ticket numbers to be used, but have never had the need to update them after this point

Comment: Thanks Ben, I wanted to update the ticketnumber after it has already been set (in an update) however when I set it the value is not retained so I’m not sure it’s possible.